# Is there a better way to show and hide?

Tags: javascript, css, show-hide

Ok so I want to display a Div from inside the page which is hidden, when clicked it fits 1005 width of the page and 100% height with scrolling content, I'm having a few issues with background stuff coming through even after extensive z-index checking and setting, as well as this on scrolling down, once you get to the bottom of the div it seems to scroll down and display the content beneath it which I dont really want it to do. ANyway I'd like to know if there is something a bit more solic, structured or just more efficient than using what i already have. Heres the coding any advice would be much appreciated.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>


<div id="ef" style="display:none; width:100%; height:120%; overflow:scroll; background-color:#f1f1f1; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; z-index:2000; padding-top:43px; "><div id="efmenubars">
            <div style="width:50px; height:40px;margin-top:7px; float:left; margin-left:8px;">
            </div><span style="display:inline-block;  text-align:center; font-family:'helvetica_bqregular'; font-size:20px; color:#333;">Post Enquiry</span>

    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('ef');"> <img src="../images/close.png" width="50px" style="float:right; margin-top:7px; margin-right:8px;" /></a>

        </div>
<p>{leftcol}</p></div>

<a class="button2" style="float:right; margin-right:12px; margin-top:19px;"  onclick="toggle_visibility('ef');">Post Enquiry</a>
```

Hope it all makes sense, sorry for the inline css very confusing I know it was a quick job need to clean it up.

Cheers

Ol

Comment: why don't you use jQuery?

Comment: Yep, with JQuery your whole `toggle_visibility` function can be replace with just `$("#" + id).toggle();`

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/aLQmRnvP | a shorter version of your function which does excatly the same... but I highly recommend switching to jQuery to achive more simplicity and functionalities as well!

Comment: @ZlatanO., musefan: jQuery will do nothing different, so it won't help to solve the problems.

Comment: Actually, the JS way is the best way to do it. The code you have is cross browser compatible. Including jQuery for this would be equivalent to bringing a rocket launcher to a pistol dual.

Comment: @Bergi how in the world you figure that out?

Comment: @mrmason: Does the toggle code work for you? Then it's fine. Or do you ask about those css background visibility things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use jquery to toggle between visiblity states.
jQuery is mostly for simplifying and enhancing your code.
So, if you really want to improve your code, use jquery.

```
.$('#idOfYorElement').toggle();
```

Just a simple one liner :)

Comment: what is this link for waht